# Putting entire website content into String value ( android )

Tags: java, android, database, hashcode

I have an assignment to hashcode ( on button click ) the contents of an entire website, and I have hit a dead end ( since I'm a beginner ). So far I managed to get this far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    EditText urlInput;
    TextView urlTxt, hashValue, saveLoc, tv4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        urlInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlInput);

        urlTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urlTxt);
        hashValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hashValue);
        saveLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saveLoc);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);

    }


    public void btnClick(View v) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Button btn = (Button) v;

        urlTxt.setText("Url entered: " + urlInput.getText());
        String urlCopy = urlInput.getText().toString();

        //problem area ahead ->
        URL uri = new URL(urlCopy);
        URLConnection ec = uri.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ec.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        int hashedSite = inputLine.hashCode();
        hashValue.setText("Hash Value: " + hashedSite);


        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(hashedSite);
        byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();
        if ((bytes[0] % 2) == 0) {
            tv4.setText("First byte is an even number: " + bytes[0]);
        } else {
            tv4.setText("First byte is and odd number: " + bytes[0]);
        }


        //        String out = new Scanner(new URL(urlCopy).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    }
}
```

The point where I'm stuck is the buffered reader, I can't get it to read the web URL from the edit text field. The last comment is one of the things I tried but it also didn't work out for me. The question is why won't the buffered reader read and save the URL?

The assignment also requires me to check the first byte of the hashed website and write it in a database ( if it's an even number ) or SharedPreference ( if it's and odd number ), but I will try to figure it out later.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've posted store's the webpage's content in the `a` variable. The `inputLine` will contain the last value returned by `in.readLine()` which is `null`.

You need to change

```
int hashedSite = inputLine.hashCode();
```

to

```
int hashedSite = a.toString().hashCode();
```

Also, it seems that you've running all this on the UI thread. In android, network related tasks should be done on a background thread. You should take a look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)